# Can't Access Constant from within Included File

Tags: constants

First of all, I'm completely sure I'm being an idiot on this one - but an hour of scratching my head and searching this site has still left me perplexed.

I'm trying to access a constant that's defined within the constructor of my plugin in an included file.  The file is included in a function that's hooked to the wp_footer action:

```
class className {
function className () {
    $this->__construct();
}

function __construct() {
    DEFINE('IMPACTMENU_IMAGES', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/impactmenu/images'); 
    DEFINE('IMPACTMENU_TEMPLATES', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/impactmenu/templates');

    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'impact_menu_html'));
} 

function impact_menu_html() {
    ob_start();
    include(IMPACTMENU_TEMPLATES . '/template.php');
    $im_footer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $im_footer;
   }
}
```

And in the template.php file:

```
echo IMPACTMENU_IMAGES;
```

I'm expecting the output to be the path to the images directory, but the output is actually simply "IMPACTMENU_IMAGES".

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that the Template Files get processed before the `wp_footer` action, so your constant is not defined at that stage.

Just to be sure, try hooking your constructor of the class to an action that is called earlier, I don't really know how early you need it, but try `init`. You could also construct your class when the Plugin is loaded, then you should be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks! I must be getting a bit confused with this because I thought that the loading order must have been the problem so moved the constant definitions to another function and hooked that to init, yet the same result.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this - why does the IMPACTMENU_TEMPLATES constant work whereas the constant that's included after this point doesn't work?  At what point are includes processed?

Comment: Can you post the code of your Plugin please?